# Will global variables in the text section be read only?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

I have found out that I can create global variables in the text section, for example:

```
section .text
    i DD 12345
```

Will this variable be read-only (since the text section is typically read-only)? And is there's anything wrong in creating global variables in the text section (other than the fact that they'll probably be read-only)?

Comment: Short answer: Yes by default. You can make the .text section writable at runtime, though.

Comment: @tux3 What do you mean "You can make the .text section writable at runtime"?

Comment: Your operating system will generally allow you to change page permissions. Look for mprotect on linux and VirtualProtect on Windows. And you can set section permissions in the binary headers.